# flot charts - how to extend x-axis to values beyond the data series in a time series chart?

Tags: jquery, flot

I would like to have a consistent x-axis for all the charts on the page irrespective of whether the data series contains the x-axis values.

I tried to specify the ticks in the options but that doesn't seem to work
thanks

```
var options = {xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%m/%d/%y" },
        ticks: [[1343692800000, "7/31/2012"], [1346371200000, "8/31/2012"], [1375228800000, "7/31/2013"]]
        };
```

Comment: have u got answer for this.please post the valid answer if u could.It would help me more

Answer (score 0):

Use the axis min and max options.  Read the [Customizing the Axes](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) section of the docs for more info.